# My sql query shows an error when updating a date value with dateadd() function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') where id_hotel=6 and id=70739' at line 1

query

```
update  prenotazione_h 
set  camera=202, dal ='2017-11-23', al=dateadd('2017-11-23',INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
where id_hotel=6 and id=70739;
```

Comment: I think you want either `ADDDATE()` or `DATE_ADD()`.  `dateadd()` is not a native MySQL function name.

Comment: Thank you very much that was my mistake :)